# Pattern matching on a datatype containing a list

Tags: list, haskell, nested, pattern-matching

So, I have defined a data type which looks something like this:

```
data SumCoolElement = Int
newtype DType = D [SumCoolElement]
```

I want to iterate over `SumCoolElements`, which I am trying to do with this code:

```
iterator :: Dtype -> DType -> Int
iterator (D lst1) (D lst2) = case (x:xs) (y:ys) of
  (D fstint:xs) [] -> fstint
  (D fstint:xs) (D sndint:ys) | fstint > sndint -> iterator (D (fstint + sndint) : xs) (D ys)
  (D fstint:xs) (D sndint:ys) | fstint < sndint -> iterator (D (fstint - sndint) : xs) (D ys)
```

The code itself is pointless, but what annoys me is that I can't even get it to run. I seem to keep running into syntax errors no matter how I format the above. Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: you don't need that nested case in the first place. the arguments to functions are  patterns, so you just write `iterator (D (x:xs)) (D (y:ys)) | x > y = iterator ....`. nested patterns are allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In expressions as well as patterns, `:` has lower priority than type application. Therefore, this kind of pattern:

```
f (D x:xs) = ...
```

will be parsed as:

```
f ((D x):xs) = ...
```

which is incorrect. You want to specify explicitly:

```
f (D (x:xs)) = ...
```

Or in your particular case:

```
(D (fstint:xs)) [] -> ...
(D (fstint:xs)) (D (sndint:ys)) | fstint > sndint -> ...
  ...
```

There is the same issue on the right side of those expressions:

```
D (fstint + sndint) : xs
```

Will be parsed as:

```
(D fstint + sndint) : xs
```

It should be:

```
D (fstint + sndint : xs)
```

Finally, the other answer by @assembly.jc is also required to fix it - the argument of the `case` expression has undefined variables. You probably meant to say that `(x:xs)` is `lst1` and `(y:ys)` is `lst2`, but note that since the second list might be empty, it is easier to go pattern matching directly:

```
iterator :: Dtype -> Dtype -> Int
iterator (D fstint:xs) [] = fstint
iterator (D fstint:xs) (D sndint:ys) | fstint > sndint = ...
...
```

Comment: This fixed it, thanks!. Would you mind helping me add another layer? I've modified SumCoolElement:

`data SumCoolElement = E Int`

I tried writing:

` (D ((E fstint):xs))) []  -> ...`, but it won't work.

Comment: That seems correct - what's the error message, after fixing everything else?

Comment: the error message? shouldn't it be "not in scope: `x`, `xs`, `y`, `ys` ..."?

Comment: Expanded the answer.